# How do I Reference a Handlebar Registered Helper in ExpressJS

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am trying to figure out how I can reference my registered handlebars helper, but the documentation isn't that clear on where the logic should exist and how it should be referenced. I have created a js file called link-shortener that contains my registered helper and then reference `linkDot` in my view file, but I get an error message

```
error Error: [pages/app/high-level-activity-feed.hbs] Missing helper: "linkDot"
   at null.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/project/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/base.js:86:13)
   at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/project/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:221:23), <anonymous>:6:87)
```

**/views/helpers/link-shortener.js**:

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('linkDot', function(str){
    if (str.length >15)
        return str.substring(0,15) + '...';
    return str;
});
```

**/views/pages/app/high-level-activity-feed.hbs**:

```
{{#each card}}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{this.title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-data-source"><i>{{this.discoverySource}}</i></p>
            {{#if reportLink}}
            <p class="card-report-link">Report: <a href="{{linkDot this.reportLink}}" class="card-data-report-url">{{this.reportLink}}</a></p>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Are you using ember.js ? It seems to me that yes if so maybe you should consider retagging your question because you don't have to create hbs files with handlebar.

Comment: I've found you're using express-hbs https://github.com/barc/express-hbs not really handlebar. Retag your question to express to find more helpful answers. You can also consider using handlebar.js : http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: @ChristopheThiry Thanks for the insight